# Firebase hosting error Error: Failed to make request to https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/releases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am deploying my React app to firebase hosting. when I create firebase init and select all options I am getting this error.
`Error: Failed to make request to https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/releases.json`
Here are all the options I am selecting.

```
C:\Users\user\git\Apps\screem>firebase init

     ######## #### ########  ######## ########     ###     ######  ########
     ##        ##  ##     ## ##       ##     ##  ##   ##  ##       ##
     ######    ##  ########  ######   ########  #########  ######  ######
     ##        ##  ##    ##  ##       ##     ## ##     ##       ## ##
     ##       #### ##     ## ######## ########  ##     ##  ######  ########

You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  C:\Users\user\git\Apps\screem

? Are you ready to proceed? Yes
? Which Firebase CLI features do you want to set up for this folder? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confi
rm your choices. Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites

=== Project Setup

First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add,
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

? Please select an option: Use an existing project
? Select a default Firebase project for this directory: screem-59e13 (screem)
i  Using project screem-59e13 (screem)

=== Hosting Setup

Your public directory is the folder (relative to your project directory) that
will contain Hosting assets to be uploaded with firebase deploy. If you
have a build process for your assets, use your build's output directory.

? What do you want to use as your public directory? build
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
? Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No

Error: Failed to make request to https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/releases.json
```

I can access this link through browser. Any ideas how to fix this or whats wroung.